# not able to create database SQLAlchemy with sqllight

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

It is the first time when I am using SQLAlchemy with sqllight.

My code looks like this:

```
#we are going to create the flask app
app = Flask(__name__)

global db
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqllite:///databse.db'
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'ca8b6694c31960d1f7ee2d1ac73c669f'

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
    
app = create_app()
```

The next step is to go the terminal and type python. The python interpreter will come and I typed "from main import db", since my file is called main I have to imported from the main.

But this is the actual error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/alex/portal/main.py", line 15, in <module>
    db = SQLAlchemy(app)
  File "/home/alex/portal/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/extension.py", line 219, in __init__
    self.init_app(app)
  File "/home/alex/portal/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/extension.py", line 326, in init_app
    engines[key] = self._make_engine(key, options, app)
  File "/home/alex/portal/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/extension.py", line 614, in _make_engine
    return sa.engine_from_config(options, prefix="")
  File "/home/alex/portal/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 817, in engine_from_config
    return create_engine(url, **options)
  File "<string>", line 2, in create_engine
  File "/home/alex/portal/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/deprecations.py", line 277, in warned
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[no-any-return]
  File "/home/alex/portal/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 556, in create_engine
    entrypoint = u._get_entrypoint()
  File "/home/alex/portal/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/url.py", line 754, in _get_entrypoint
    cls = registry.load(name)
  File "/home/alex/portal/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 365, in load
    raise exc.NoSuchModuleError(
sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:sqllite
```

If you have any suggestions please let me know.

Plus I am trying to put this code in the "_ *init* _.py" from the script in order to have a cleaner code.

Answer (score 0):

You have mis-spelled `sqlite` as `sqllite`:

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///databse.db'
```

But even if you fix that you're going to have additional problems, because you're redefining `app` at the end of your code. Here's a working example, which is a simplified version of [this example from the documentation](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/quickstart/#query-the-data).

```
from flask import Flask, request, redirect, url_for
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "sqlite:///databse.db"
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = "ca8b6694c31960d1f7ee2d1ac73c669f"

db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String, unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String)

    def as_dict(self):
        return {c.name: getattr(self, c.name) for c in self.__table__.columns}


with app.app_context():
    db.create_all()


@app.route("/users", methods=["GET"])
def user_list():
    res = db.session.execute(db.select(User).order_by(User.username)).scalars()
    users = res.fetchall()
    return [user.as_dict() for user in users]


@app.route("/users", methods=["POST"])
def user_create():
    user = User(**request.get_json())
    db.session.add(user)
    db.session.commit()
    return user.as_dict()


@app.route("/user/<int:id>")
def user_detail(id):
    user = db.get_or_404(User, id)
    return user.as_dict()
```

You can create a user entry:

```
$ curl http://localhost:5000/users -H content-type:application/json \
  -d '{"username": "alice", "email": "alice@example.com"}'
{
  "email": "alice@example.com",
  "id": 1,
  "username": "alice"
}
```

Get a list of users:

```
$ curl http://localhost:5000/users
[
  {
    "email": "alice@example.com",
    "id": 1,
    "username": "alice"
  }
]
```

Get details on a single user:

```
$ curl http://localhost:5000/user/1
{
  "email": "alice@example.com",
  "id": 1,
  "username": "alice"
}
```

Etc.